# Always try-catch-finally for exceptions? Central error management?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I wonder if I always have to use try-catch-error blocks that clutter the code a lot, if I want to catch an error.

Or can I somehow define a global error catcher?
Especially regarding Java EE Webapps.

For every unhandled ex I'd like to log to a specific file, and display a general error page to the user.

I thought I might achieve that with aspects. But for aspects to catch on `@AfterThrowing`, I too have to introduce try-catch blocks. And as there is no central class for the backing-facades, I would have to surround every backing method with trycatches.
Then the aspect would take them, but I need something to catch without explicit throws exceptions.

How could I to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `declare soft` construct.  This will wrap the given exception in a `SoftException` (an AspectJ-specific RuntimeException) so that it does not need to be explicitly handled.  Then you can handle all of these exceptions with some `AfterThrowing` advice.

`declare soft` only exists in code style AspectJ (ie- there is no annotation for this).  So, you will need to compile your code using the AspectJ compiler, but you can still use load-time weaving for this if you like.

See here:
http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick-other.html

And here:
http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/declare-soft.html

---

Here's a code snippet that shows how it can be done:

```
aspect ErrorHandler {
  declare soft : Exception : within(*);
  after() throwing(Exception e) : handler(e) {

    // do something...
  }
}
```

This will route *all* exceptions in your system through your custom error handler.  And you won't need to explicitly catch or throw them.

It's simple and powerful.  Perhaps too powerful, though.  I'd recommend refining and being more precise about exactly which exceptions should be softened and which ones need to be advised, but this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do this in every method.

You should not catch an exception that you can't "handle".  Handling means more than just rethrowing or logging or printing a stack trace.  I think handling means implementing a meaningful recovery strategy.

It might mean "the buck stops here": You're Gandalf on the bridge at the edge of a layer boundary, and no exception shall pass.  You don't want users to see nasty messages, so you catch and route them to a friend, easy to understand page that tells them what to do next.

Finally isn't always necessary, but it's perfect for cleaning up resources like file handles and database cursors.

If you cannot handle an exception, there's no shame in adding the throws clause to the method signature and letting callers figure out what they want to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, there is no mechanism to do this - Java does not have what you're looking for.

However, depending on your circumstances, it might be possible.

**`web.xml` Exception Handler**

The `web.xml` file allows you to define a URL to be used to handle specified exception type. (See, for example, http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.ExceptionType).
Since you're writing a webapp, you may be able to just let the exceptions throw all the way to the top, and then handle them this way.

**Custom interceptor**

You mention that you have backing-facades. Depending on how they're being constructed, you may be able to put a generic proxy in front of them to catch and handle the exceptions you're interested in. You've tagged your question with `spring`, to you might want to look at Spring AOP Proxies.

There might be other ways to get what you want, but it will depend on the specifics of your application's architecture.

Comment: The question is not about Java, but about AspectJ.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg - It's about JEE webapps, and it's tagged `java`, `spring` and `aspectj`. There's no reason not to offer a solution that's pure Java.

Comment: True enough.  I was thrown off by your first line "there is no mechanism to do this".  In pure JEE, there is not, but the solution in AspectJ is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The finer control you have of the exceptions, the easier it will be to debug/provide a meaningful message.

To which extent? I would link that to the complexity / expected lifetime of your application. The bigger those are, the finer should be your handling.

I see two main approachs:

- User approach: You get at least one exception handling for each UI action (so you can say: "Do not push that button AGAIN").
- Debugger approach: Every method has its control.

Keep in mind that most handling could be just logging of rethrowing of the exception.

More to the point, most probably, your Java EE framework will have log options in its configuration files (many of them working with java.util.loggin or log4j). You could tweak that; of course, what is send to each log category will depend of the framework implementation (so maybe not all ERROR messages will be Exceptions).